# Java Extract part of string

Tags: java, string, extract

I want to extract the value `0.81` from the following string, but I don't know how. Using JSON doesn't work, because as far as I know it's not proper JSON code.

> [{"boundingbox":{"size":{"height":239.23,"width":239.23},"tl":{"y":46.15,"x":166.92}},"name":"152:0.81,","confidence":0.9}]

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: It's valid json, but the `0.81` is not a value of its own. You need to get the value of "name", split it on ":", an take the second part of the split result. Should be a nice exercise so I am not gonna give a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

If this is JSON, which it appears to be, load it up as a JSON Object and

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(thatString);
JSONObject jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String name = jObj.getString("name");
```

Which would then give you a string "152:0.81,", an odd name - however I would then split it:

```
String[] tokens = name.split(":");
```

tokens[0] will be 152

tokens[1] will be 0.81,

Answer (score 0):

It actually is valid Json, so you could use Json library (any of them), to load the Json to an Object and access the value - If you're having problems loading this into an Object, perhaps you can change your question and show us the error?

If, by any chance, you might get a response that *isn't* valid Json, you might use a regex:

If you always have that same pattern, something like:

```
\"name\":\"\d+:(\d\.\d+),\"
```

Your value will be in capturing group one.

If you're not sure how to use regexes in Java, just search SO or Google, there's a ton of examples.

Comment: Good suggestion to fail-over to a regex when JSON parse finds invalid JSON.

Comment: I find it extremely hard to believe that any application's API that is producing JSON would sporadically produce invalid JSON. Sounds highly, highly unlikely to me.

Comment: Yes it's unbelievable but I have got many errors while parsing it in JSON. 
The 152 is dynamic how to change the regex to fit that, it's a variable.

Comment: @nickb Yes, it's unlikely, but I have no clue what API the OP is using.